# Releasing different builds of same application (One with reduced functionality)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, release

I almost finished an application and I want to thave two different releases. The only difference would be that one of releases is full featured application while the other one shouldn't have some functions (eg. Create new project...).

For example the LESS featured program should not have the create project option in its menu (While the codes are the same).

I want to know if you have expirience with this case, should I make 2 different soloutions, or is there buildeoptions in `Visual Studio` that can take care of this cases? or maybe it is possible to use some special `Attributes`...how does one do such thing!

Comment: Do you want to only turn off the features or do you want to not distribute the code involved?

Comment: Yeah I want two have 2 different builds, one full, one with less features but I want to see if thisis possible using a single soloution/

Comment: To do it in a single solution you can use preprocessor directives, and build the solution once with definied directive, and once with undef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using the preprocessor directive `#if`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.71).aspx

Basically:

- Define a build configuration called `trial`
- In this build configuration, define a conditional compilation symbol called `TRIAL`
- Update your code to activate/deactivate features depending on whether the constant is defined or not

  ```
  #if TRIAL
  // hide menu
  #endif
  ```